# fullpage.js - show all tooltips on hover a single circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

**PROBLEM**

I'd like to have all the tooltips show up on the screen when I hover on one of the .nav-fp circles. I'm wondering if there is a way of doings this without over-riding the jquery.fullpage.js file.

**WHAT DID NOT WORK**

I've tried manually with the code below but have not had any success:

```
//Navigation Tooltips
$(function(eOut) {
    $(".fp-tooltip").hide();
    $("#fp-nav").hover(function() {
        $(".fp-tooltip").show();
    }, function(eOut) {
        $(".fp-tooltip").hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle or something please

Comment: Sorry, there's too many lines of code in fullpage.js to add a jsfiddle for this. I was hoping the maker of the plugin can address this.

Comment: Just add js and css from github as external resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using just CSS for it an overriding the default one:

```
#fp-nav ul:hover .fp-tooltip{
    right: 20px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1056/)

This way we are telling fullpage.js to show the tooltips whenever any part of the list is hovered.